# pass the value entered by the user to a url and display results

Tags: android, rest

Basically im trying to pass the value entered by the user to a url and display results based on that.... as im getting no errors im not too sure whats wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated

When i click on the button nothing happens... i have the eventlistener added etc

```
package com.example.jsonrestclient;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected TextView tv1;
protected TextView tv2;
protected TextView tv3;
protected TextView tv4;
protected EditText ET1;
protected String ET2;



 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ET2 = ET1.getText().toString();
    }

    public void button1OnClick(View v) {
        String patientString = HttpHandler.HttpGetExec(HttpHandler.baseURI + ET2);

        String patientFName = "NOT FOUND",
                patientLName = "NOT FOUND",
                DOB = "NOT FOUND",
                patientGender = "NOT FOUND",
                hospitalNumber = "NOT FOUND";
        JSONObject patientObj = null;

        try {
            patientObj = new JSONObject(patientString);
            patientFName = (String) patientObj.get("PatientFName");
            patientLName = (String) patientObj.get("PatientLName");
            DOB = (String) patientObj.get("DOB");
            patientGender = (String) patientObj.get("PatientGender");
            hospitalNumber = (String) patientObj.get("HospitalNumber");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv1.setText(patientFName + " " + patientLName);
        tv2.setText("DOB" + "  " + DOB);
        tv3.setText("Gender" + " " + patientGender);
        tv4.setText("Hospital" + " " + hospitalNumber);

    }
}
```

Comment: is your onClick for the button defined in your xml? if so, show the code

Comment: ET2 is evaluated before you write anything in ET1

Answer (score 0):

As njzk2 mentions, you're evaluating ET2 far too early.

You're doing this in the onCreate(), which means ET2 will already be assigned before the user has a chance to type anything into ET1, so it'll always be empty.

What you need to do is move `ET2 = ET1.getText().toString();` down, as the first line in `button1OnClick`.

Presumably `button1OnClick` is bound to the `android:onClick` parameter in your view xml?

Also, what is HttpHandler? I couldn't tell from your imports. I'm not sure what it is, but it may be worth considering moving the rest call out into an AsyncTask.